# Call derived class function implementation from base

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

We have the following situation:

```cs
public interface IHandle<T> {
 void Handler(T param);
}

public abstract class AbsBase : IWasLeftOutForBrevity {
 public void SomeFunction<T>(T param) {
   // ... see question ...
 }
}

public class Derived : AbsBase, IHandle<int>, IHandle<decimal> {
 public void Handler(int param) {
   // ...
 }
 public void Handler(decimal param) {
   // ...
 }
}
```

In the above code, it is probably a well seen bit of code whereby a derived class implements a number of handle functions given a particular type.

We have a generic IoC container that injects instances of `IWasLeftOutForBrevity` and generically calls `SomeFunction` on the abstract base class with a given type. The `SomeFunction` is meant to call the associated `Handler` function on the `Derived` class as part of its operation.

Given that the base interface is `IWasLeftOutForBrevity`, and we use this in generic infrastructure, we don't have direct access to the `Handler` methods.

We would normally do something like:

```cs
GetType().InvokeMember("Handler",
 BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
 null,
 this,
 args
);
```

or a similar `GetType().GetMethods("Handler", ...)`/`GetType().GetMethod("Handler", ...)` to find the method to call on the instance.

An added "complication" is that the type used in `IHandle` is often an implementation of a common interface.

I was wondering if there is any cleaner way of accessing the `Handler` methods without doing this kind of reflection (for instance trying to get away from the magic "Handler" string) that is more type safe?

### Update

We have not been able to use the cast options (`this is IHandle<T> handle`). There is a process flow that uses a generic top level interface to pass data around. `AbsBase.SomeFunction` is then called with the top level interface, and the cast breaks because the derived class doesn't implement the top level interface.

i.e.

```cs
public interface IDataAbstraction { }

public class SomeFunctionalHandle : IDataAbstraction { }

public class Derived : AbsBase, IHandle<SomeFunctionalHandle>{
 public void Handler(SomeFunctionalHandle param) {
   // ...
 }
}

// later in a decorator
IWasLeftOutForBrevity instance = getInstance(); // get instance of derived
IDataAbstraction data = getData(); // get data based on IDataAbstraction
instance.SomeFunction(data);
```

In the generic service infrastructure the code passes around `IDataAbstraction` and then passes it to the `SomeFunction`.

Comment: You could try to cast your instance to the interface and call it´s handler-method within `SomeMethod`. But again, this sounds like a design-flaw, your base-class should never rely on any of its deriving ones.

Comment: in your someFunctin simply do this

(this as IHandle).Handler(param);

Comment: @MichaelRandall @HimBromBeere I assume you are meaning some `Register` action (on the base, or on a different "manager") that the implementation would use to push `Handler` functions to? Not sure how to accomplish that generically. We didn't what the devs having to implement an extra call, just to implement the necessary interface. Having now seen the comments, I can see the flaw of design - thanks.

Comment: @AnonymousCodes Only use `as` if you expect the cast to fail, and always test for `null`. If you don't expect the cast to fail, use a normal cast -- `((IHandle<T>)this).Handler(param)`

Comment: Is there something that prevents `AbsBase` from implementing `IHandle<T>` with an abstract method that then forces the `Derived` class to implement it? Then have `AbsBase.SomeFunction` call that abstract method?

Comment: @DavidJetter type `T` is different per implementation of the base. The base is used in generic decorators to interact with user code. The user code inherits the base but poses no restrictions on what `T` or the number of `T`s need to be implemented. The generic infrastructure passes data in via an external common service so the decorator only knows the top level interface that `T` has to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do this:

```
public abstract class AbsBase
{
    public void SomeFunction<T>(T param)
    {
        if (this is IHandle<T> handle)
        {
            handle.Handler(param);
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle error case
        }
    }
}
```

---

Before reaching this, I played with some other approaches using reflection and compiled expressions. I think they're all inferior to the code above so I haven't included them in my answer, but they're in the edit history if you're interested.

**EDIT:** Ah, turns out @HimBromBeere suggested this in the comments first, while I was still experimenting with reflection.